# How to add custom paramater (GET / POST) to a service reference (PHP WSDL) in .net

Tags: c#, php, .net, wsdl, xdebug

In my c# project I have a service reference to a php web-service. For debugging purposes (`XDEBUG`) I need to send a specific `GET` variable for every method call. How can I tell .net, that every call to the php service gets a "`?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=ECLIPSE_DBGP`" at the end?

Comment: do you want to send this extra variable via query string or through headers?

Comment: I think either should work according to the xdebug documentation. So I would go the easiest way.